# Exchange Mgmt Shell - You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-or' operator

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

i have some problem while executing this command in EMS:

```
PS>Set-AddressList -Identity "some_list" -RecipientFilter {((((RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox' -or RecipientType -eq 'MailContact') -and -not(CustomAttribute1 -ne $null)) -and (CustomAttribute12 -eq 'aa' -or CustomAttribute12 -eq 'aa, bb')) -and (-not(CustomAttribute13 -eq 'function_boxes') -or SamAccountName -eq 'some_user'))}


At line:1 char:325
+ ... _boxes') -or SamAccountName -eq 'some_user'))}
+                    ~
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-or' operato
r.
At line:1 char:326
+ ... _boxes') -or SamAccountName -eq 'some_user'))}
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'SamAccountName' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:325
+ ... _boxes') -or SamAccountName -eq 'some_user'))}
+                    ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:1 char:64
+ Set-AddressList -Identity "some_list" -RecipientFilter {((((Recipient
Typ ...
+                                                                ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block.
At line:1 char:363
+ ... me_user'))}
+                    ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:364
+ ... me_user'))}
+                    ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:365
+ ... me_user'))}
+                    ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression             ~
```

I can't figure out what's the problem?

Comment: try to enclose `SamAccountName -eq 'some_user'` in `()`. Let me know..

Comment: Bingo! :) This is solution. But i wonder how someone set the script like mine into Exchange Address List, cause this is original Recipient Filter from Exchange Mgmt GUI. I tried to overwrite exisiting script with original again (for test purposes) and there were those errors...

Comment: I think this was a bug that was fixed by a service pack / update. Not sure what one.